# Separate angular translate into multiple json that load on view

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angular translate for internalization. The problem i am having now is how to separate angular translate into serveral json files that load on view.
eg: Page1En.json, Page2En.json, Page1JP.json, Page2JP.json

I am expecting something like this:

```
$translateProvider.translations('en',
  {
     GlobalView: 'GlobalEN.json', // for header, footer
     view1: 'Page1En.json',
     view2: 'Page2En.json'
  })
.translations('jp',
  {
     GlobalView: 'GlobalJP.json',
     view1: 'Page1JP.json',
     view2: 'Page2JP.json'
  });
```

and the json file will load accordingly when the specific view is being loaded.